# How to remove an icon in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, icons, android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable Icon here :

```
Icon(   
   painter = 
      if(condition) {
           painterResource(id = .....)
      }else{
           //want to remove icon here
      }     
)
```

I want  to remove the icon inside else statement. what should I put there?

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `Icon`.

```
 if(condition){
      Icon(painterResource(id = xxx),"contentDescription")      
 }
```